# Implementing Google Search Appliance results into website

Tags: .net, google-search, google-search-appliance

I’m interested to hear peoples preferred methods or approaches to implementing the search results from a Google Search Appliance into an existing website. More specifically how do people prefer to implement/embed the search results into their existing site and persist the surrounding website elements (menus, membership etc) around the search results.

As far as I am aware there are 3 different approaches.

- Sub-domain, handle everything in the 
  xslt – create a search.mysite.com which is completely handled by google xslt and embed surround site components in xslt.
- Embed search results into existing site using an iframe – Use the existing website and just use an iframe to import results into page.
- Embed results into existing site by using server side processing – This is how I have previously integrated search into a site using a combination of bespoke dev and the [GSALib project](http://gsalib.codeplex.com).

I would be interested to hear if anyone has other suggestions, and were people have benefited or regretted using the above approaches.

Comment: Did you ever turn anything up?

Answer (score 3):

The first and third approaches are by far the most common I've seen. I work with the GSA regularly, and work on a lot of search interfaces specifically. I do a lot of approach #3 actually, but I've never really had regrets with one implementation or another - there are simply some things that can only be done through the third approach, so if you want one of those things that's what you have to do. There may be other considerations as well: as a consultant, I build things for others to maintain. Will my client have an easier time maintaining a solution in their current environment rather than XSLT? Most developers aren't especially comfortable with XSLT.

I've seen one other variation - using XSLT to rewrite XML into either HTML or another XML format, then consuming that through a custom server-side application. I'm not really sure what the justification for that was, it seemed unnecessarily complex to me, but it wasn't my choice.

One other possibility that I haven't seen yet is the use of AJAX calls to front ends on the appliance, which would presumably return XML or JSON from a front end.